# make txt file from data received by serial port

Tags: python

I am trying to store data from usb port to a txt file using python, I send data from mobile phone using ble uart and chip NORDIC nRF52840 and I want to store it all untill I dont send more data, how do I close the loop? should I use a command like "STOP"? maybe do a list of data? I dont know how to implement this.

```css
import serial
archi1=open("datos7.txt",'w')
ser=serial.Serial('COM17',baudrate = 115200, timeout=15)

try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print ("Reading open.")
except:
    print ("Error.")
    exit()

while True:
    data = ser.read(500)
    data = data.replace(b'\r',b'')
    data = data.replace(b'\x1b',b'')
    dataASCII = data.decode("ascii")
    archi1.write('Envio de datos empezado.\n')
    print(data, end='')
    if archi1.write('Los datos obtenidos son:|%s|' % (dataASCII)):
        archi1.write('\nEnvio de datos terminado.')
        
        break
archi1.flush()
archi1.close()
```

Comment: it could be simpler if you send some command because normally it can't say if it is end of data or there are some data which needs little longer time to arrive to computer. And it may be useful to first send byte with length of message - and other side first would have to read single byte and later use it in `read()` to wait for correct number of data. You and send `NON STOP COLOR` but it may get first only `NON `, and later only `STOP` without `COLOR` and it may think that you want to stop connection.

Comment: I am not sure about how to implement that to my code

Comment: I don't know how you send data but if you use Python to send data then you can get `size = len(data)`  and convert it to 4bytes using `size_4bytes = struct.pack("I", size)` and next send `size_4bytes` and `data`. And then receiver first has to `size_4bytes = read(4)` next `size = struct.unpack('I', size_4bytes)[0]` and finally `data = read(size)`

Comment: other method is to send some unique char at the end of data, and then recevier can read until it get this char,  and it will know that it is end of message.